# Overlapping Date Formatting in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I just started exploring these spreadsheet scripts on Google Docs. I want to write a script that finds date overlaps between projects (changes the bg color of the given cell to red) and creates a new column that shows the number of conflicts on that project type. If you can provide me some examples or a way to do it, I would be very appreciated.

Here is my data set.

[Data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=0AnUwp_KUEAF3dE4wNG5nWnhZRlFicGdMNnhFWXBaOXc&output=html)

What I tried is this. This only works for the first column though.

```
function formatting() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1'); // get the sheet
  var columnF = sheet.getRange(1, 6, sheet.getLastRow(), 1).setBackgroundColor('white'); // get all the rows and clear colors
  var columnG = sheet.getRange(1, 7, sheet.getLastRow(), 1).setBackgroundColor('white'); // get all the rows and clear colors
  var fValues = columnF.getValues(); // get the values
  var gValues = columnG.getValues();
  var day = 24*3600*1000
  Logger.log(gValues)
  var startDay1 = parseInt(fValues[0][0].getTime()/day)
  var endDay1 = parseInt(gValues[0][0].getTime()/day)
  var startDay2 = parseInt(fValues[1][0].getTime()/day)
  var endDay2 = parseInt(gValues[1][0].getTime()/day)
  if (startDay1<endDay2 && startDay2<endDay1) {sheet.getRange(1, 6, 1, 1).setBackgroundColor('red')}
  else {sheet.getRange(1, 6, 1, 1).setBackgroundColor('green')}
  }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  In most cases, we won't do work for you unless you have have us the work you have done thus far.  Please provide that.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please read the [FAQ here](http://stackoverflow.com/help) before posting... your question is not a programing question but a direct code request .*Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions

Comment: @Brian :-) simultaneity...

Comment: Thanks, I updated the question with my minimal understanding of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer in case anyone is interested.

```
function formatting(m, d) {
    try {
        var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1'); // get the sheet
        var output = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet2'); // output sheet        
        output.clear()

        // Going to need the column for project type
        var counts = {};
        var eValues = sheet.getRange(1, 3, sheet.getLastRow(), 1).getValues();
        var columnF = sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), 1).setBackgroundColor('white'); // get all the rows and clear colors
        var columnG = sheet.getRange(1, 2, sheet.getLastRow(), 1).setBackgroundColor('white'); // get all the rows and clear colors
        var columnD = sheet.getRange(1, 4, sheet.getLastRow(), 1).setBackgroundColor('white').clearContent(); // get all the rows and clear colors
        var columnCritical = sheet.getRange(1, 7, sheet.getLastRow(), 1).setBackgroundColor('white').clearContent(); // get all the rows and clear colors
        var fValues = columnF.getValues(); // get the values
        var gValues = columnG.getValues();
        var day = 24 * 3600 * 1000


        // loop through all the rows in the dataset


        for (var r = 0; r < (fValues.length - 1); r++) {

                var startDay1 = parseInt(fValues[r][0].getTime() / day);
                var endDay1 = parseInt(gValues[r][0].getTime() / day);

                // loop through all the rows for given date

                for (var z = 0; z < (fValues.length - 1); z++) {

                    var startDay2 = parseInt(fValues[(z)][0].getTime() / day);
                    var endDay2 = parseInt(gValues[(z)][0].getTime() / day);

                    // if the date is the same go to the next one
                    if (startDay1 == startDay2 && endDay2 == endDay1) continue;

                    // check for conflicts
                    else if (startDay1 < endDay2 && startDay2 < endDay1) {

                        //Here is our conflict!!!;



                        var projectn = r + 1
                        if (counts[projectn] !== undefined) { // strict(!) comparison
                            // add one to this projects count
                            counts[projectn] += 1;
                        } else {
                            // create the first count for this project
                            counts[projectn] = 1;
                        }
                    } else {
                    // if there is no conflict
                    }
                } //end of for loop for var z

                // change the background of the counts to red and set values
                if (counts[r + 1] == undefined) {
                    sheet.getRange(r + 1, 4, 1, 1).setValue(counts[r + 1]).setBackground('green');
                } else {
                    sheet.getRange(r + 1, 4, 1, 1).setValue(counts[r + 1]).setBackground('red');
                }
        } // end of for loop for var r


        // show if there is any errors 
    } catch (e) {
        Logger.log(e.lineNumber + ' - ' + e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The code needed to loop through each row.  Not sure how you want to contend with the last project, since there is no date to compare it to.

An easy way to keep count of the projects flagged red is to create a javascript object (projects), and store each of the projects, and their counts.  Here is some documentation on javascript objects: [Javascript.info - Objects](http://javascript.info/tutorial/objects#iterating-over-keys-values)

```
   function formatting() {
  try{
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1'); // get the sheet

    // Going to need the column for project type
    var projects = {};
    var eValues = sheet.getRange(1, 5, sheet.getLastRow(), 1).getValues();

    var columnF = sheet.getRange(1, 6, sheet.getLastRow(), 1).setBackgroundColor('white'); // get all the rows and clear colors
    var columnG = sheet.getRange(1, 7, sheet.getLastRow(), 1).setBackgroundColor('white'); // get all the rows and clear colors
    var fValues = columnF.getValues(); // get the values
    var gValues = columnG.getValues();
    var day = 24*3600*1000
    Logger.log(gValues)
    // loop through all the rows in the dataset
    for(var r = 0; r < (fValues.length - 1); r++){
      var startDay1 = parseInt(fValues[r][0].getTime()/day);
      var endDay1 = parseInt(gValues[r][0].getTime()/day);
      var startDay2 = parseInt(fValues[(r+1)][0].getTime()/day);
      var endDay2 = parseInt(gValues[(r+1)][0].getTime()/day);
      if (startDay1<endDay2 && startDay2<endDay1) {
        sheet.getRange((r+1), 6, 1, 1).setBackgroundColor('red');
        var projectName = eValues[r][0];
        if(projects[projectName] !== undefined) { // strict(!) comparison
          // add one to this projects count
          projects[projectName] += 1;
        }else{
          // create the first count for this project
          projects[projectName] = 1;
        }
      }
      else {
        sheet.getRange((r+1), 6, 1, 1).setBackgroundColor('green');
      }
    }

    // updating is done, need to create the counts 
    // shove the results in column L
    var rowCount = 1;
    for(var key in projects) {
      var val = projects[key];
      sheet.getRange(rowCount, 12, 1, 1).setValue(key+": "+val);
      rowCount += 1;
    }
  }catch(e){
    Logger.log(e.lineNumber + ' - ' + e);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have another question. What if I would like to check if each row overlaps with the rest of the rows. I mean start and end day for the project will remain the same and it will iterate through all rows.